# Dashboard List Item making one Active and the others unactive?

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a dashboard on the left side of the screen and it is not updating which list item should be 'Active'.  Constantly it keeps attempting to, but once the screen refreshes it doesn't work.  I feel like I have tried every combination, but I know something has to work.

Below is the HTML for the list Items:

```
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li class="sidebar-list-item">
        <a href="/home">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home"><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"/><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"/></svg>
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-list-item">
        <a href="/solarGraph">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-pie-chart"><path d="M21.21 15.89A10 10 0 1 1 8 2.83"/><path d="M22 12A10 10 0 0 0 12 2v10z"/></svg>
          <span>Solar Graph</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-list-item">
        <a href="/windGraph">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-pie-chart"><path d="M21.21 15.89A10 10 0 1 1 8 2.83"/><path d="M22 12A10 10 0 0 0 12 2v10z"/></svg>
          <span>Wind Graph</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sidebar-list-item">
        <a href="/dataUpload">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-inbox"><polyline points="22 12 16 12 14 15 10 15 8 12 2 12"/><path d="M5.45 5.11L2 12v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-6l-3.45-6.89A2 2 0 0 0 16.76 4H7.24a2 2 0 0 0-1.79 1.11z"/></svg>
          <span>Data Upload</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried the below Java script to attempt to change the Active state, however it didn't work.  It appears every time I click a link it appears for a split second than nothing changes once page reloads:

```
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const currentPath = window.location.href;
        const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

        //console.log(links);
        links.forEach(link => {
          //console.log(link.href); // this will log the href of each link
          if (link.href === currentPath) {
            link.parentNode.classList.add('active');
          } else {
            link.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
          }
        })
      });

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-list-item");
  var activeItem = localStorage.getItem("activeItem");

  if (activeItem) {
    listItems.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item.dataset.item === activeItem) {
        item.classList.add("active");
      } else {
        item.classList.remove("active");
      }
    });
  }

  listItems.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Remove "active" class from all list items
      listItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.remove("active");
      });

      // Add "active" class to clicked list item
      this.classList.add("active");
      localStorage.setItem("activeItem", this.dataset.item);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use getAttribute("href") to get the tag href attribute value, the href prop is already computed value with location.host.

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const currentPath = localStorage.getItem("activeItem") ?? window.location.pathname;
    const links = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");

    links.forEach(link => {
        const hrefAttr = link.getAttribute("href");
        link.parentNode.dataset.item = hrefAttr
        
      if (hrefAttr === currentPath) {
        link.parentNode.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        link.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
      }
        
      link.addEventListener("click", appNavigate)
    })
});

function appNavigate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const { currentTarget } = event
    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar-list-item");
    
    listItems.forEach(function(item) {
        item.classList.remove("active");
    });

    currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add("active");
    localStorage.setItem("activeItem", currentTarget.parentNode.dataset.item);
}
```